# How to get the colour of where a user clicked using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Where I work, we have different accessibility rules to the standard Web Content Accessibility Guidelines.

Therefore I am looking at making a chrome extension so that when the user clicks on 2 parts of a web page, it can take these 2 colours and calculate the contrast ratio.

I know how to calculate the contrast ratio from the 2 RGB values, but I cant seem to find anything to allow me to get the colour of the pixel where the user clicked as part of a chrome extension.

I would basically like to be able to have similar basic functionality to an extension like ColorZilla.

Comment: Inspect/debug ColorZilla to see its implementation, obviously.

Comment: I found an open source extensions [chromeEyeDropper](https://github.com/kepi/chromeEyeDropper), you can explore it.